# Swift 3: Class and Struct Optionals

Tags: swift, class, struct, option-type

I'm transitioning to Swift 3 from coding Obj-c for a long time. So I think I understand the idea of optionals but I'm confused on this problem. Say I have a class called Monster. And I also have struct called Town.

```
struct Town {
    var population: Int = 0
    var name: String?
    var hasSherrif: Bool?
    var hasTheater: Bool?
    var hasTownhall: Bool?
    var hasSchool: Bool?
    var hasGeneralStore: Bool?
    var numOfHomes: Int = 0
}
```

and Monster...

```
class Monster {
    var town: Town?
    var name: String?

    func moveToTown(_ thisTown: Town) {
        town = thisTown
        if let strName = name, let strTownName = town?.name {
            print("\(strName) moved to \(strTownName)")
        } else if let strName = name {
            print("\(strName) move to a town with no name")
        } else {
            print("The monster moved to a town. Might help if you give stuff names, just saying.")
        }

    }
}
```

In moveToTown(_ thisTown: Town), how can I check if Monster has no name but Town does? I'd like to change this line:

```
} else if let strName = name {
```

to something like

```
} else if let strName = name && town?.name == nil {
```

and then add another conditional

```
} else if strName == nil && let strTownName = town?.name {
}
```

Thanks and if there's anything in general that could be cleaned up feel free to critique.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `town?.name` because `town` is not optional.

And no need for the `town = thisTown` line. Just name the parameter as `town`.

I would write it this way:

```
func moveToTown(_ town: Town) {
    if let name = name {
        if let townName = town.name {
            print("\(name) moved to \(townName)")
        } else {
            print("\(name) move to a town with no name")
        }
    } else {
        print("The monster moved to a town. Might help if you give stuff names, just saying.")
    }
}
```